# Ladakh India where the moon (Ramadan moon) is sighted but not in rest of India

Tags: observational-astronomy, the-moon, natural-satellites, moon-phases

Today 22 May 2020 around 3 p.m Ladakh India sighted new moon(Ramadan moon) but not in rest of India.I read many articles acc. To them it is not visible today, then how it was seen from Ladakh... .